# Does $\langle Fv_j, Fv_j \rangle = \langle F^*v_j, F^*v_j \rangle$ imply that $F$ is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthonormal

> Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of an inner product space $V$ and a linear $F:V\to V$ s.t. for all $j$: $$\langle Fv_j, Fv_j \rangle =  \langle F^*v_j, F^*v_j \rangle.$$ Does it imply that $F$ is normal?

At first, I thought that we just need to set $T:=F^*F-FF^*$ and then $\langle Tv_j, v_j \rangle=0$ would imply that $T=0$ but it doesn't (any non-zero matrix with zeros on the diagonal is a counterexample).

It looks like the problem boils down to

> Let $A^*A-AA^*$ have zeros on the diagonal. Does $A^*A=AA^*$ hold?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. It
is easy to see that $F$ is not normal. Then
$F^*F-F F^* = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Let $v_1 = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}(1,1)^T, v_2 ={1 \over \sqrt{2}} (1,-1)^T$. These are orthonormal and 
$\langle v_k ,(F^*F-F F^*)v_k \rangle = 0$ for $k=1,2$.

Comment: Isn't it in our case, $x=y$? we are forming the innerproducts $\left<v,Tv\right>$ and not $\left<w,Tv\right>$, I feel like this is not applicable or am I not following correctly?

Comment: @DimitarM.H.: You are correct, I missed the fact that the indices were the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is false.

Let

$$F = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and let $v_j$ be the standard basis.

Then, you can check

$$FF^* = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}; \quad F^*F = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

so that $F$ is not normal, and on the other hand:

$$
Fv_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}; \quad F^*v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \\
Fv_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}; \quad F^*v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \sqrt2\end{pmatrix} \\
Fv_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \sqrt2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}; \quad F^*v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

which pairwise all have the same length.

Note: to cook up this counterexample, I started by writing down a general $2\times 2$ matrix (i.e. with entries $a,b,c,d$) and took the standard basis to see what conditions would be imposed on $a,b,c,d$. In this case, it's just $b^2 = c^2$ which will yield a symmetric or anti-symmetric (and thus normal) matrix.

So, moving to a $3\times 3$ matrix, and only focusing on the off-diagonal (as you note, the diagonal basically "isn't in play" here) to come up with conditions on the remaining $6$ entries. Start out easy, choose one of them to be $1$, the next to be $0$, and then start choosing other coefficients to *avoid* symmetry/anti-symmetry. Choosing other entries equal to $1$ or $0$ yielded a normal matrix, that is when I had the idea to switch in a $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I was just about to write "Would you mind sharing how did you construct this counterexample?" when I saw your update. Many thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I realized I risked it looking like magic, so I decided to go back and add some thoughts. Glad you found this helpful.